# Directly store object properties in array of objects, without creating full object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, javascript-objects, variable-assignment

```
var cartArray = [];
//in a loop
    var cartObject = {};
    cartObject.item_name = 'NAME';
    cartObject.quantity = number;
    cartObject.amount =  number;
    cartObject.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;
    cartObject.subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total;
    // store
cartArray[i]=cartObject;
```

can we directly store like on the fly without having full information of cartObject

```
var cartArray=[]
cartArray[i].item_name ='NAME'
cartArray[i].quantity =number
```

this thing works like

```
var cartArray=[]
cartArray[i]={}// it needs to be defined for each i
cartArray[i].item_name ='NAME'
cartArray[i].quantity =number
```

can we bypass this thing

Comment: Only if you created the object before.

Comment: Why not use `cartArray[i] = {item_name: 'NAME', quantity: number, …};`?

Comment: I don't have all the information of object, and I want to store in property if required.

Like at some point I want to have added new property like "discount" in array index  n. to store new property

Comment: Yes, you can add properties to an object at any time. But the object must already exist in the array for a `cartArray[i].discount = number` assignment to succeed. If you did create the objects in the first loop, and then afterwards add a new `.discount` property to them, it will work just fine. Did you try it?

Comment: (I would however recommend that you create the objects with all their properties initially, and keep their values `undefined` until the point where you get the information).

Comment: ```G[2] = {"name":"Prateek"}``` Later if I need to store mobileVar in G[2]
```G[2] ={"mobileVar":1233}``` it overwrites previous object
```G[2].mobileVar=1233``` works but only if  i have already defined object in firstly
I don't know if I have defined name before or not

Comment: Do you know how many objects there will be? Then you can initialise them all as empty objects (`G[i] = {}` or `G[i] = {name: undefined, mobileVar: undefined}`), and later set your property values at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
var cartArray = [];
//in a loop
cartArray[i] = {
    item_name: 'NAME',
    quantity: number,
    amount: number,
    total: cart.amount * cart.quantity,
    subtotal = cart.subtotal + cart.total
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to update `G[2].mobileVar=1233` but I don't know if I have defined the object already

In that case, you can write

```
if (!G[2]) G[2] = {};
G[2].mobileVar = 1233;
```

to create the object only if it does not already exist in the array.